# bad argument #1 to 'updateOutput' (2D or 3D(batch mode) tensor expected)

Tags: lua, torch, conv-neural-network

I'm trying torch since last week and I have a problem with the temporal convolution.
I'm working on the UCR datasets (see http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/time_series_data/) and when I try a convolution, I have this error:

```
/home/arthur/torch/install/bin/luajit: /home/arthur/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Sequential.lua:44: bad argument #1 to 'updateOutput' (2D or 3D(batch mode) tensor expected)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'updateOutput'
    /home/arthur/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Sequential.lua:44: in function 'forward'
    testTimeSeries.lua:59: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    ...thur/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:145: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00406670
```

I have this model in lua:

```
net = nn.Sequential()
net:add(nn.TemporalConvolution(5, 1, 3))
net:add(nn.ReLU())
net:add(nn.Linear(trainset:sizeData(), 150))
net:add(nn.ReLU())
net:add(nn.Linear(150, #classes))      -- #classes is the number of class in the data
net:add(nn.LogSoftMax())
net = net:cuda()
```

I train my model with `:train()` (but manually, I have the same error).
I understand how convolution works but I don't know how solve this.
I suppose I have to resize my input but how ?
If you can help me, I will be thankful !!

Thanks,
Arthur

ps: sorry for my english

Comment: what is the ```:size()``` of your input tensor? It probably just needs a reshape.